# How can I reskin the Headband of the Ninjitsu for a steampunk campaign?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, house-rules, equipment, steampunk

My DM is running a steampunk *Pathfinder* campaign, and he's banned strictly magical objects and weapons. However, he has said that if we can reskin it to fit within the world (i.e. a wand is more akin to a blaster weapon, weapon enchantments are things like batteries and small jars of acid strapped to weapons, that sort of thing), then he will allow them.

He has very recently given us a large wad of cash after we captured a terrorist alive and presented him to the local military. I would like to purchase a Headband of the Ninjitsu for my rogue character, as it gives bonuses to stealth and sneak attack rolls. I'm not certain how I would reskin it to fit within the world, or how it would give me those bonuses.

**How can I reskin the Headband of the Ninjitsu to fit in a steampunk campaign?**

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] when you get a chance. This is a pretty good first question. Have you made any attempts to reskin it? I assume the items need to remain in the same slot and have the same mechanical effects? Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: Thank you! To answer your questions… yes, I have thought about how it might be reskinned for the game, and the best I could come up with was a cloth that fully covered my head rather than just a simple headband, which would grant the necessary bonus to stealth. However, this would not directly improve my attack rolls. And no, it need not remain in the same slot (I reskinned a Stormlure to wear as a backpack because the battery necessary was enormous) but it is the only slot left available.

Comment: You may receive some Primarily Opinion Based close votes due to the nature of an idea generation question. However I feel that you have given fairly reasonable restrictions and this is something a user with steampunk genre knowledge should be able to give a good answer too.

Comment: Ah, thank you ^^ it's my first question so I was a little nervous about asking it, heh.

Comment: @Aurora I am not sure if this is what you are looking for exactly, but there are already ways to combine multiple magical items into one. You end up paying 1.5 times the price for them. You could take the effects that you would like on a magical wand or item (headband of the ninjitsu) and pay 1.5 times the price to apply it to another item. I could see the same effects being applied to a cloak, cape, or coat as an example.

Comment: Oh! I did not know that! It might work well in my favour. I'll look into it and pester my DM about it.

Comment: @Aurora yeah, best of luck!

Comment: I voted to close because if 20 different people have a reskin idea for this, you will get 20 different answers, all actually correct. Reskinning is pretty much all flavor if the mechanics behind the item doesn't change. Flavor can be discussed with your GM, and no matter what we say here, that will only give you ideas and not actually help you convince your GM of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: after a few insightful comments, and a few minutes of scheming with my DM, we came up with an agreeable compromise!

The bonuses to bluff checks were reskinned as the headband fully covering my face and preventing the opponent from seeing through my thoughts in combat, and the insight bonus to stealth attacks was applied to my dagger in the form of a matte covering which prevented glare from reflecting off the blade.

However, being unable to find a good, non-magical reason for being able to sneak attack creatures with concealment, or to make one free reposition or feint, we opted to remove those special abilities.

Thank you to everyone who helped me come to this conclusion!